# Requisição ajax(jquery) de multiplos formulários funcionando apenas 6 vezes

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, formulário, assincronismo

estou a tentar enviar multiplos formulários com ajax e jquery mas ele está a enviar apenas 6 formulários. Eis o código Jquery:

```
$('form').each(function(){

      var values = $(this).serialize();
                $.ajax({
                      url:"/inq/responder",
                      type:"POST",
                      data: values,
                      success:function(data)
                      {
                         
                      },
                      beforeSend: function(){
                          $('#loader').css({display:"block"});
                          },
                        complete: function(){
                          $('#loader').css({display:"none"});
                      }
                }); 
    });
```

Alguém já passou por isso e resolveu?

Comment: Entre o 6 e 7, não há nenhuma diferença? Ou gerando alguma divergência de dados em relação aos demais?

Comment: Não há diferença pois quando elimino o sexto formulário, o sétimo que passa a ser o sexto é enviado.

Comment: Está rodando local ou no server? Se for no server, sabe se tem limitação de requisição?

Comment: Posta o códigos dos forms se for possível.

Comment: Tanto local como na nuvem está a dar o mesmo erro.